# Rails migrations - change_column with type conversion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I already google'd aroung a little bit and seems there's no satisfying answer for my problem.

I have a table with column of type string.
I'd like to run following migration:

```
class ChangeColumnToBoolean < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def up
        change_column :users, :smoking, :boolean
    end
end
```

When I run this I get following error

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  column "smoking" cannot be cast automatically to type boolean
HINT:  Specify a USING expression to perform the conversion.
: ALTER TABLE "users" ALTER COLUMN "smoking" TYPE boolean
```

I know I can perform this migration using pure SQL but still it would be nicer if I could do it with Rails. I went through Rails code and seems theres no such possibility, but maybe someone knows a way?

I'm not interested in:
- pure SQL
- dropping the column
- creating another column, converting data, dropping original and then renaming

Comment: But that the only way as far as I know.. you have to create column, migrate and remove old column...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since I'm using Postgres, I went with SQL solution for now.
Query used:

```
    execute 'ALTER TABLE "users" ALTER COLUMN "smoking" TYPE boolean USING CASE WHEN "flatshare"=\'true\' THEN \'t\'::boolean ELSE \'f\'::boolean END'
```

It works only if one has a field filled with true/false strings (such as default radio button collection helper with forced boolean type would generate)

Comment: This is bad since whenever you rebuild your DB, you're going to have to rerun this SQL statement.

Comment: @DonnyP if I put it in a migration? Srsly?

Comment: @DonnyP if by "rebuilding the database" you mean "rebuilding the schema of the database" - the recommended way to do this is via `rake db:structure:load` / `rake db:schema:load` and not via running all the migrations.

Answer (score 120):

If your strings in `smoking` column are already valid boolean values, the following statement will change the column type without losing data:

```
change_column :users, :smoking, 'boolean USING CAST(smoking AS boolean)'
```

Similarly, you can use this statement to cast columns to integer:

```
change_column :table_name, :column_name, 'integer USING CAST(column_name AS integer)'
```

I am using Postgres. Not sure whether this solution works for other databases.

Comment: Just to avoid anyone confusion: yes, you're stating your new column twice. Think of it as confirming you want to do this and not giving instructions how turn foo into a bool

Answer (score 35):

Not all databases allow changing of column type, the generally taken approach is to add a new column of the desired type, bring any data across, remove the old column and rename the new one.

```ruby
add_column :users, :smoking_tmp, :boolean

User.reset_column_information # make the new column available to model methods
User.all.each do |user|
  user.smoking_tmp = user.smoking == 1 ? true : false # If smoking was an int, for example
  user.save
end

# OR as an update_all call, set a default of false on the new column then update all to true if appropriate.
User.where(smoking: 1).update_all(smoking_tmp: true) 

remove_column :users, :smoking
rename_column :users, :smoking_tmp, :smoking
```

Comment: Yeah, it'a a solution, but as I stated, not a one I was looking for. Also it's wery bad in terms of speed - on a large production database it would take ages to run.

Comment: @MichałSzyndel You can use [update_all](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all) instead of the block which will generate only one SQL statement. Have added example.

Comment: Also, you can use `user.smoking.to_boolean` if you have strings like "Yes" and "No" in the original, non-boolean column. It handles it nicely.

Answer (score 9):

So right for boolean in postgres:

```
change_column :table_name, :field,'boolean USING (CASE field WHEN \'your any string as true\' THEN \'t\'::boolean ELSE \'f\'::boolean END)'
```

and you may add some more `WHEN` - `THEN` condition in your expression

For other database servers, the expression will be constructed based on the syntax for your database server, but the principle is the same. Only manual conversion algorithm, entirely without SQL there is not enough unfortunately.

The syntax `change_column :table, :field, 'boolean USING CAST(field AS boolean)'` is suitable only if the contents of the field something like: true / false / null