# Changing Columns Type in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I had problems performing the `heroku run rake db:migrate` command when trying to change a table column type. I saw on stack overflow you have to use a special command for PG. I then tried running rails d migration ChangeExpirationDateType, but it didn't seem to work. My question is how can I delete that change column migration, or just fix this issue in general?

```
> heroku run rake db:migrate
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.8613
==  ChangeExpirationDateType: migrating =======================================
-- change_column(:users, :expiration_date, :date)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "expiration_date" cannot be cast automatically to type date
HINT:  Specify a USING expression to perform the conversion.
: ALTER TABLE "users" ALTER COLUMN "expiration_date" TYPE date/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in `async_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:435:in `block in log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:430:in `log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:127:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:389:in `change_column'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:625:in `block in method_missing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:597:in `block in say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:597:in `say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:617:in `method_missing'
/app/db/migrate/20140420080240_change_expiration_date_type.rb:3:in `change'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:571:in `exec_migration'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:554:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:294:in `with_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:553:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:709:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:959:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1005:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `block in transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:210:in `within_new_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1005:in `ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:958:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:920:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:916:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:916:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:764:in `up'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:742:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:42:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: What type is `expiration_date` now?

Comment: A String, and I wanted to change it to Date.

Comment: What format are the strings in?

Comment: What do you mean by format?

Comment: What do the dates look like inside the database? `'2014-04-20'`? `'Sunday April 20 2014'`? Something else? Basically, you'll need to build an expression that converts the strings to dates so that you can including an appropriate USING clause in the ALTER TABLE.

Comment: They have different formats. Is there any way for me to check the type? It may still be a String on my local machine.

Comment: You can trying `using expiration_date::date` to use a raw cast but that might fail on some values, if it does then you have to manually normalize the date formats. I'm guessing that you're using SQLite in your development environment or you'd have encountered this problem already.

Comment: Yeah I'm using SQLite. Is there anyway I can get heroku to stop trying to migrate with the ChangeColumnName migration so I can at least create a remove, add migration to go around the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075173/rails-migrations-change-column-with-type-conversion

Comment: You can check the Rails environment inside your migration to do different things in different places. Once you get this sorted out you should install PostgreSQL in your dev environment and start developing and testing on PostgreSQL. Database portability is largely a myth unless you do it the hard way (i.e. by hand with exhaustive cross-database testing).

Comment: Thanks for your help mu, I'll do so. I decided to just drop the db and  run heroku run rake db:migrate without the changecolumn migration.