# Rails: Effects of changing the data type of an existing column with existing data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, type-conversion

I could be asking this in the wrong place so go easy and point me in the right direction if I am.

I can't get my head around how changing the data type of an existing column in an existing table with existing data in Rails will effect any app I am working on.

If I have a boolean column called `football`. The `football` can be either true or false. Either, I have a football or I don't. I realise that, *for example*, the football can sometimes be loaned. So, I want to change the data type of the column football to be a string. The value of the string can be true, false or loaned.

How bad a time am I going to have after running the migration for this? What will happen to my existing data? What do I need to do to mitigate against messing up all my existing data? And, am I asking this question in the right place?

Answer (score 2):

If you change the column type from boolean to string in **rails** then you have no worry because the existing data will automatically change into string. Like if you have boolean **true** this will automatically convert into string "true".

FYI, I checked this on my system ;)

Comment: So, `true` will change to "true" and `false` to "false"?

Comment: If you are conscious about your live data then create small app in rails and test on some dummy data before run migration on live data.  ;)

Comment: FYI, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075173/rails-migrations-change-column-with-type-conversion

Answer (score 2):

If I were you I would do this by creating a new column, then updating everything from the old column, and then removing the old column, and renaming the new one. Also I wouldn't save a boolean as "true" or "false" either (which Rails should give you by default if you DO just change the type)... If I were you I would create an [enum](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) for this column.

First your migration:

```
class ChangeFootball < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change

    # Add the new column. Use an integer type, so you can set up an Enum in your model
    add_column :examples, :football_new, :integer, default: 0

    # Set up the new column values for all your existing records:
    Example.where(football: true).update_all football_new: 0
    Example.where(football: false).update_all football_new: 1

    # Now remove the old column:
    remove_column :examples, :football

    # Finally, rename the new column to the same as the old one
    rename_column :examples, :football_new, :football

    # Oh, and add an index:
    add_index :examples, :football
  end
end
```

Now set up the enum in your model:

```
enum football: { own: 0, lost: 1, misplaced: 2, loaned: 3 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I will read into this but you took too many steps from my lost/misplaced/loaned comment. I am editing the question.

Comment: Now that you have edited your question, I think that @QuibaishBhatti's answer is the right one for you. However, I still think you should look into using an integer column with an enum for this, rather than a plain string.