# In Rails: How is existing data affected by data type change?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4, type-conversion

I'm working on a Rails app and would like to change the datatype for an existing column. It's currently a DateTime type, and I want to change it to a Date type. I found a way to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191405/change-a-column-type-from-date-to-datetime-during-ror-migration), but in this case, the person was not worried about preexisting data.

Right now, I plan to generate a migration...

```
rails g migration change_my_column_in_my_talbe
```

...and make the following change:

```
class ChangeMyColumnInMyTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :my_table, :my_column, :date
  end
end
```

My question is: will the existing data be converted to a Date type, or will I need to create a rake task to convert the values for all of my existing DateTime values?

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33761645/rails-effects-of-changing-the-data-type-of-an-existing-column-with-existing-dat) in which the conversion was from Boolean to String, and it seemed like the change would be automatic for existing data. I just want to be sure before I jump into making this change.

I'm using Rails version 4.2.0 and MySQL version 5.6.27 Homebrew. Any advice on this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `change_column` method, data conversion will be handled by the specific database adapter you are using. For example, with `mysql` adapter, `change_column` will call `ALTER TABLE tbl_name MODIFY COLUMN col_name DATE`. The data conversion from DATETIME to DATE will truncate the times.

Futhermore, MYSQL DATETIME to DATE performs rounding, conversion to a DATE value takes fractional seconds into account and rounds the time, '1999-12-31 23:59:59.499' becomes '1999-12-31', whereas '1999-12-31 23:59:59.500' becomes '2000-01-01'. Either way, the `change` method IS NOT reversible for the `change_column` method.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#using-the-change-method

If you plan on reversing this migration, use the `reversible` method instead.

Comment: I am using `mysql`; I should have included that in my original question. Thank you for this explanation and for providing the link!

Answer (score 2):

`change_column` is going to be translated into an `ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN` SQL statement, at which point how the casting is handled is up to your database, so the full answer depends on which database you're using. However, it's a pretty safe bet that your database can convert between datetime and date without trouble.

That said, there's no better way to know than to test it!

Comment: I worked out a way to test it and everything looked good. Thanks for your help!