# Rails Postgres Datatype Mismatch - "cannot be cast automatically to type date"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, rails-activerecord

I migrated from sqlite to Postgres so I can push to Heroku, and receive an error when running $ heroku run rake db:migrate:

```
 ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM     "schema_migrations"
Migrating to ChangeCheckIn (20160726015859)
(0.7ms)  BEGIN
== 20160726015859 ChangeCheckIn: migrating      ====================================
-- change_column(:listings, :check_in_date, :date)
 (1.3ms)  ALTER TABLE "listings" ALTER COLUMN "check_in_date" TYPE date
(0.7ms)  ROLLBACK
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "check_in_date" cannot be cast automatically to type date
HINT:  You might need to specify "USING check_in_date::date".
: ALTER TABLE "listings" ALTER COLUMN "check_in_date" TYPE date
```

When I initially built the model for :listing, check_in_date was type:date, but I changed it via migration to a string and in schema it is currently a string. The error below is referencing the initial migration and old data type before I changed it to string.

I then created a new migration (below) per this question on SO and received a new error(below): [Rails migrations - change_column with type conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075173/rails-migrations-change-column-with-type-conversion)

```
change_column :listings, :check_in_date, 'string USING CAST(check_in_date AS string)' 

PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  type "string" does not exist
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `string` type in PostgreSQL, you want `text` or `varchar`. SQLite lets you get away with this because it considers any unrecognized type to be an alias for `text`. There is, however, the `t.string` method in migrations but that creates a `varchar` column so you probably just have a bit of terminology confusion.

You want something more like this:

```
change_column :listings, :check_in_date, 'text using cast(check_in_date as text)'
```

or using PostgreSQL-specific casting:

```
change_column :listings, :check_in_date, 'text using check_in_date::text'
```

Note that `t.string` in a migration creates a `varchar(255)` column in the database and that `varchar(n)` and `text` are internally identical (except for an extra length check on `varchar(n)`) in PostgreSQL so you'll generally just go with `text` unless you have specifically need the length restriction inside the database.

Comment: Do I have do to this migration with every record that was initially a string in sqlite before I switched from sqlite to pg?

Comment: The migration will change the whole *column* at once from a date to a string, The column is currently a `date`, right?

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't have chosen the word "record." What I meant was, in my schema there are multiple columns which are strings (check_in_date, check_out_date, hotel, bookingengine, etc...). Do I need to run additional separate migrations for each of these to eliminate same errors I posted regarding check_in_date?

Comment: If the current type is string then you'd use `'date using cast(... as date)'` for each column. If that raises exceptions then you have to fix the format (YYYY-MM-DD is best) before changing the column types.

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful.

Comment: I noticed that even though it isn't documented, this syntax also works: `change_column :listings, :check_in_date, :text, using: 'check_in_date::text'` (tested on Rails 6.0.3.4)